# Is business intelligence development studio available in express editions?

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence

Is there anyway to use Business Intelligence Development Studio with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition? Or is it available for Enterprise and Developer Editions? If it is possible have BIDS standalone installment?

Comment: Why would you install the express version if you donèt have access to the desoigner ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the below MSDN link, `Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS)` is available in *SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services*.

[**Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2 - Development Tools**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Dev_tools)

You can download the Express with Advanced Services from the below link. Note that there are `32-bit` and `64-bit` versions of the install. You need to choose the correct version.

[**Microsoft SQL Server2008 R2 RTM - Express with Advanced Services**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25174)

Personally, I haven't tried the Express with Advanced Services edition. So, I am not sure how much of BI development is possible with the Express edition.